# Importing data from an https server

Tags: import, web-access

When trying to import data from an https request I get the following error message.

```
request = HTTPRequest[ 
  <|"Scheme" -> "https", "Method" -> "GET", "Domain" -> "api.nasa.gov"
  , "Path" -> "planetary/earth/imagery"
  , "Query" -> {
      "lon" -> 100.75, "lat" -> 1.5, "cloud_score" -> True
    , "date" -> DateString[{2014, 02, 04}, "ISODate"]
    ,  "api_key" -> "DEMO_KEY"
    }
  |>
]
```

> ```
> HTTPRequest[
>   URL: https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/earth/imagery?... =2014-02-04&cloud_score=true&api_key=DEMO_KEY 
>   ContentType: None
> ]
> ```

Generates `HTTPRequest`. The hyperlink works fine when clicking on it.

When trying to `Import` (or use `URLRead`) to bring the data

```
Import[request]
```

> {"error" -> {"message" -> 
>       "Requests must be made over HTTPS. Try accessing the API at: \
>       https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/earth/imagery/?lon=100.75&lat=1.5&date=\
>       2014-02-04&cloud_score=true&api_key=DEMO_KEY", 
>       "code" -> "HTTPS_REQUIRED"}}

Comment: I think it has something to do with the output being as HTTPRequest.  If you use the following, it seems to work fine: `Import["https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/earth/imagery/?lon=100.75&lat=1.5&date=2014-02-04&cloud_score=true&api_key=DEMO_KEY"]`  (At least it returns the same data as when I click the link)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make a long story short: you need `...imagery/?...` not `...imagery?...` in your url.

When you click the hyperlink you will be redirected to the correct one, that is why you see an expected result. The `301` redirect response takes you there.

In principle MMA can handle redirects 301/302 and I don't know enough to judge this behavior so I'd ask WRI support how to classify this issue.

Meanwhile add `/`:

```
Import@HTTPRequest[<|"Scheme" -> "https", "Method" -> "GET", 
   "Domain" -> "api.nasa.gov", "Path" -> "planetary/earth/imagery/",(*!!*) 
   "Query" -> {"lon" -> 100.75, "lat" -> 1.5, 
     "date" -> DateString[{2014, 02, 04}, "ISODate"], 
     "cloud_score" -> True, "api_key" -> "DEMO_KEY"}|>]
```

> ```
> {"date" -> "2014-02-04T03:30:01", "cloud_score" -> 0.0392665, 
>  "resource" -> {"dataset" -> "LC8_L1T_TOA", "planet" -> "earth"}, 
>  "service_version" -> "v1", 
>  "id" -> "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC81270592014035LGN00", 
>  "url" -> "https://earthengine.googleapis.com/api/thumb?thumbid=\
> 0d15ad8d2af6d8d0a6b083672514fae7&token=\
> 86cd0d3233be25e65e5f055ce5d2ed3c"}
> ```